# Excel time formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007 and am trying to write a time comparison formula.

I wish to compare two times entered into two cells with the following conditions:

1. If the times are within 5 minutes of each other display the earlier time in a third cell.
2. If the two times are outside 5 minutes apart it would be the later time to instead be displayed in the third cell.
3. The earlier time will not always be in cell 1 and the later time not always in cell 2, they may be reversed. For example: the earlier time may be in cell 1 or cell 2 and conversely the later time may also be in cell 1 or cell 2, the result time will always be in cell 3.

Is this possible and if so how would the formula be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the times are in A1 and F1, you could use this formula in the results cell:

```
=IF(ABS(A1-F1)*1440>5,MAX(A1,F1),MIN(A1,F1))
```

This takes the absolute value of the difference in times, so it doesn't make any difference which cell is earlier.  Times are stored as fractions of a day, and there are 1440 minutes in a day, so the difference is converted to minutes.  If that difference is greater than 5, it outputs the higher of the two values.  If not, it outputs the lower value.

Note that if you get strange looking results, it will likely be that the output is formatted as a number so that you're seeing the internal time or date/time representation.  Just format the output as a time.

Comment: .... Apart from one minor issue... If in your reply cellsA1 and B1 are obviously adjacent, however in my workbook they aren't. For example A1 and F1 and in this instance the data in the cells In between corrupts the answer. Is the a solution to this? Thankyou again.

Comment: @AndyM, I adjusted the answer for your case with non-contiguous cells.  The difference is listing the cells separated by commas rather than as a range in the MIN and MAX functions.

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou, I'm new to this site but will be back next time I need to create a spreadsheet above my pay grade!